# Hibernate Configuration with Spring MVC for testing

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to set up testing with an H2 in-memory database for my Spring MVC application.

Right now, all my configuration for Hibernate is in a Java file `PersistenceConfig.java` and it holds the `SessionFactory` with all the Hibernate configuration.

However, my testing context is in XML because it was easier that way - is there any way to make this work? Right now, when I run my tests, all I get is errors because it can't connect to MySQL, which it shouldn't even be trying to do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd">

  <!-- annotation support -->
  <context:annotation-config/>

  <!-- support for transaction -->
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.package.configuration" />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.package.models" />

  <!-- H2 datasource -->
  <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
  </bean>

  <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" ignore-failures="DROPS">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:reset_database.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:create_testdata.sql"/>
  </jdbc:initialize-database>

  <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="persistenceConfig" class="com.package.configuration.PersistenceConfig"/>
  <bean id="userDao" class="com.package.models.user.UserDao"/>
</beans>
```

My tester class looks like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/test-context.xml",
    "classpath:/spring/spring-security.xml"})
@Transactional
public class UserTest {
  private UserDao userDao = new UserDao();

  private static User user;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
  private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void initUser() {
    user = new User(...);
  }

  @Test
  public void testSave() throws Exception {
    userDao.save(user);
    User foundUser = userDao.findByUuid(user.getUuid());
    assertEquals(foundUser.getUuid(), user.getUuid());
  }
}
```

The `sessionFactory` is not being Autowired and the `userDao` never gets it.

My `UserDao` calls `PersistenceConfig.sessionFactory()` in its constructor, and `PersistenceConfig` supplies it with a `sessionFactory` that corresponds to MySQL. I need to somehow switch that out for a H2 `sessionFactory`.

Am I going about this completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when you are injecting you `sessionFactory` it is loading `PersistenceConfig.java` with it, generally when you inject one object others dependencies are injected too. If I were you, I would use `hibertane.hbm.xml` to configure you test connection, it overrides all others configurations...

Comment: Well, my `sessionFactory` isn't getting Autowired at all - it's null.

Comment: You could try to set a JNDI name to de H2 dataSource and then put a breakpoint in the test class and try to get this dataSource from the context to see if it is been created. Just a thought...

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the `UserDao` object yourself

```
private UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
```

Spring can only inject an object whose lifecycle it manages.

Get a `UserDao` bean from your context (`@Autowired` it) if you have one (or add one if you don't).

Comment: But I'm not trying to Autowire the `UserDao`. I'm trying to Autowire the `sessionFactory`.

Comment: @AVP Is `UserTest`'s `sessionFactory` nulll or `UserDao`'s? Spring can't inject beans into objects it doesn't control.

Answer (score 0):

For testing you can use your PersistenceConfig. Instead of setting up a complete new context I would split the distinct beans into [@Profile](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) configurations:

```
 @Profile("test")
 @Configuration
 public class TestConfig {

     @Bean public DataSource dataSource() {
         // return Test bean
     }

 }

 @Profile("production")
 @Configuration
 public class ProductionConfig {

     @Bean public DataSource dataSource() {
         // return productiv bean
     }

 }

@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class DatasourceTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // assertions
    }

}
```